# Making excel macro for file scanning more stable

Tags: vba, excel

I was curious if anybody could provide suggestions on how I can make an excel macro more stable.

The macro prompts the user for a path to a folder containing files to scan. The macro then iterates for every file in this folder.

It opens the excel file, scans **Column D** for the word *fail*, then copies that row of data to the data sheet in the excel file where this macro is programmed.

For the most part the macro runs perfectly but sometimes I get run time errors or 'excel has stopped working' errors. I can scan through 5000+ files at a time and the macro takes a while to run.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
Sub findFail()    

Dim pathInput As String 'path to file
Dim path As String 'path to file after being validated
Dim fileNames As String 'path to test file

Dim book As Workbook 'file being tested
Dim sheet As Worksheet 'sheet writting data to
Dim sh As Worksheet 'worksheet being tested
Dim dataBook As Workbook 'where data is recorded

Dim row As Long 'row to start writting data in
Dim numTests As Long 'number of files tested
Dim j As Long 'counter for number of files tested
Dim i As Long 'row currently being tested
Dim lastRow As Long 'last row used

Dim startTime   As Double 'time when program started
Dim minsElapsed As Double 'time it took program to end

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

j = 0
i = 1
row = 2

Set dataBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set sheet = Worksheets("Data")
sheet.Range("A2:i1000").Clear

startTime = Timer

'-----Prompt for Path-----

pathInput = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter path to files. It must have a \ after folder name.", _
                     Title:="Single Report", _
                     Default:="C:\Folder\")
If pathInput = "C:\Folder\" Or pathInput = vbNullString Then 'check to make sure path was inputed
    MsgBox ("Please enter a valid file path and try again.")
    Exit Sub
Else
    path = pathInput 'path = "C:\Temp\212458481\" ' Path for file location
    fileNames = Dir(path & "*.xls")   'for xl2007  & "*.xls?" on windows
'-----begin testing-----
    Do While fileNames <> "" 'Loop until filename is blank
        Set book = Workbooks.Open(path & fileNames)
        Set sh = book.Worksheets(1)
        lastRow = sh.UsedRange.Rows(sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count).row

        If sh.Cells(lastRow, 2).Value - sh.Cells(1, 2).Value >= 0.08333333 Then
            Do While sh.Range("D" & i).Value <> "" 'loop untile there are no rows left to test
                If sh.Range("D" & i).Value = "Fail" Then 'record values if test result is false
                    sheet.Range("A" & row).Value = book.Name
                    sheet.Range("B" & row).Value = Format(sh.Range("B" & i).Value - sh.Range("B1").Value, "h:mm:ss")
                    sheet.Range("C" & row).Value = sh.Range("A" & i).Value
                    sheet.Range("D" & row).Value = Format(sh.Range("B" & i).Value, "h:mm:ss")
                    sheet.Range("E" & row).Value = sh.Range("C" & i).Value
                    sheet.Range("F" & row).Value = sh.Range("D" & i).Value
                    sheet.Range("G" & row).Value = sh.Range("E" & i).Value
                    sheet.Range("H" & row).Value = sh.Range("F" & i).Value
                    sheet.Range("I" & row).Value = sh.Range("G" & i).Value
                    row = row + 1
                    Exit Do
                End If
                i = i + 1
            Loop
            j = j + 1
            dataBook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(2, 1).Value = j
        End If
        book.Close SaveChanges:=False
        fileNames = Dir()
        i = 1
    Loop
numTests = j
Worksheets("Summary").Cells(2, "A").Value = numTests

minsElapsed = Timer - startTime
Worksheets("Summary").Cells(2, "B").Value = Format(minsElapsed / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If there are any formulas in the workbooks you are opening using `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` at the start of your code and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` at the end may help speed things up

Comment: @Logan Fleisher can you share where are you getting these errors ? what line ?

Comment: Unrelated, but [Application.FileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836226.aspx) is a cleaner way to get a folder from the user than an InputBox.

Comment: It might help the cause if you tell us what run time error you're getting and what line of code is highlighted when you click "Debug" from the error dialog. Also, to speed up your code, investigate the `.Find()` function of the `Range` object. I'm not sure how many rows are in each of your sheets you're opening, but `.Find()` will find the "Fail" text much more quickly than looping through every row of 5000+ worksheets. (You'll still have to open each workbook, but loop `.Find()` results instead of loop every row.)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. There are not specific lines there the macro is failing, rather it just seems to get overwhelmed. I will try the suggestions to improve memory usage and speed up the 'searching'.

Comment: For Excel 2010 or above I recommend looking into [Power Query](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a7E29H5ZUmE). Other ways to read from Excel files without opening them are [ADODB](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692882.aspx) and [External references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell-range-in-another-workbook-c98d1803-dd75-4668-ac6a-d7cca2a9b95f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the same dataset as you we, can not definitively supply an answer but I can recommend the below which is related to the error you are seeing.

Try freeing/destroying the references to `book` and `sh`.

You have a loop that sets them:-

```
Do While fileNames <> "" 'Loop until filename is blank
    Set book = Workbooks.Open(path & fileNames)
    Set sh = book.Worksheets(1)
```

However the end of the loop does not clear them, ideally it should look as below:-

```
    Set sh = Nothing
    Set book = Nothing
Loop
```

This is a better way to handle resources and should improve memory usage.

As a poor example, without it your code is saying, `sh` equals *this*, now it equals *this* instead, now it equals *this* instead, now it equals *this* instead, etc...

You end up with the previous reference that was subsequently overwritten being a sort of orphaned object that is holding some space in memory.

Comment: Did it process all without issue then?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your case, you may use the following to make it faster -by turning off excel processes that you don't really need at the time of your macro execution-

```
Sub ExcelBusy()
        With Excel.Application
        .Cursor = xlWait
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .StatusBar = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
        End With
End Sub
```

In your sub

```
Dim startTime   As Double 'time when program started
Dim minsElapsed As Double 'time it took program to end

Call ExcelBusy
...
```

As a comment, you never set back screenupdating to true in your sub, that may lead to strange behavior in excel, you should turn everything to default after you are done with your stuff.

OT: Some processes can't be optimized any further -sometimes-, by what you are saying -scanning over 5k files?- surely it's going to take a time, you need to work in how to communicate the user that is going to take a while instead -perhaps an application status bar message or a user form showing process?-.